# Boolean Algebra with new definition

Tags: boolean-algebra

For two sets A,B with $B\subset A$ let us define:

$$A-B:=A\setminus B $$

as the monotone difference. If $B$ is not a subset of $A$ then $A-B$ is not defined. Now my question. How to portray
$A \cup B$ with only $-$ and $\cap$?

Thanks for hints and/or solutions.

My idea:
$$A \cup B=(X-A-B)^c$$

But I guess I cannot use complement.

So this would mean:
$$A \cup B=X-(X-A-B)$$

Or, if $\cap$ has to be used:
$$A \cup B=X-(X-(A-(A \cap B))-(B-(A \cap B))-(A \cap B))$$

Comment: Given $A,B$ and the algebra $R$ they are  subsets of, the answer is obvious, right?  At least a few minutes of playing around should get you the complement of the set you want, and then you have it.

Comment: @rschwieb but i cannot use complement can i?

Comment: You can if you can mention $R$ (in @rschwieb's comment) but not if you cannot mention it. In fact $A-B=A\cap B$ if I understand you correctly, wherever the LHS is defined. Thus all you can ever get from subsets $A$ and $B$ is some subset of one or both.

Comment: @rschwieb What do you say about my idea?

Comment: @calculatormathematical I’ve not seen anyone try to use Boolean operations as partial operations on the entire class of sets.  If that is your context, then no, I guess you don’t have complement .  Are you sure you are not operating within the power set of some set?

Comment: @rschwieb I am not really sure. I only know the definition of this ,"monotone difference". I guess this could be right.

Comment: @calculatormathematical I've never heard the expression "monotone difference" so I don't know the context.  It seems like it would be hard to make progress if you don't know either.